# NSTableView, NSArrayController, CoreData - Footer View to refresh list

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data, nstableview

I have an `NSTableView` bound to an `NSArrayController` which fetches some entries from core data.

I would like to have a custom view cell in the bottom of that `NSTableView` so that when the user scrolls to the last element in the table, a scrolling indicator will appear instead of a table view cell.

This is similar to what happens in the twitter for mac application, where you scroll to the bottom of the list to fetch more results.

Because the binding is done in the nibs, I'm not quite sure if I need to change that and set the `NSTableView` datasource to my windowcontroller and increase the number of rows with 1.

Is there a simple way to do this?